# Camel exception routing in a split EIP

Tags: java, exception, apache-camel

I'm integrating a CSV file input with a larger system, and I want to set it up such that individual lines of a CSV (which are split up by `split`) that don't parse correctly are send to a hospital queue, and all other working lines are converted into an object and aggregated into a list.  However, I'm having trouble getting messages with exceptions thrown within a `split` to be routed elsewhere, and not appear in the aggregator at the end of the split.  In order to simplify it, I've written a unit test that throws an exception within a split, and I've tried to get that working.  I'm splitting the string `1\n2\n3\n` into three messages, throwing an exception on one of them, and concatenating the remaining strings at the end.

```
public void configure() throws Exception {

    onException(Exception.class)
        .handled(true)
        .to("log:dead?level=ERROR");

    from("direct:test")
        .split(body().tokenize("\n"), new MyAggregationStrategy())
            .process(new ThrowMyException())
        .end()
        .to("mock:out");
}

@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException {

    MockEndpoint out = getMockEndpoint("mock:out");
    out.expectedMessageCount(1);

    template.sendBody("direct:test", "1\n2\n3\n");

    assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
}
```

ThrowMyException Controller: Just throwing an Exception

```
@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("[" + exchange.getIn().getBody() + "]");
    if (exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class).trim().contentEquals("2")) {
        System.out.println("Throwing exception");
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

MyAggregationStrategy: Just concatenating strings

```
@Override
public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
    if (oldExchange == null) {
        return newExchange;
    }
    oldExchange.getIn().setBody(
            oldExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class) + 
            newExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class));
    System.out.println(oldExchange.getIn().getBody());
    return oldExchange;
}
```

What I expect is that the `onException` handler, as I've indicated it is to handle the exception (`handled(true)`), it will consume the exception thrown by the controller when it gets the message '2', and I will get the result `13` printed out by the aggregator.  I do get the line printed out by the `onException`handler:

> ERROR dead - Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOnly, BodyType: String, Body: 2]

But the Aggregator then returns '123' instead of '13'.

I've also tried using a deadLetterChannel

```
errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("log:dead?level=ERROR")
```

And I've also tried specifying `continued(false)` in the `onException` handler, but no luck.

I realise I can look for exceptions in my aggregator by looking at `exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT)`, and then not aggregate it.  So I do have a solution.  But if there's a way to do it in my route using `onException` or `errorHandler`, I would much prefer that.

Comment: Interesting case - strange indeed. One guess could be that that in your aggregator you are concating the string from oldexchange and newexchange. I am wondering since handled is true, the oldexchange is the one containing the exception but since you are concating it still comes with it.

Comment: Could be that either need to change your aggregator or like you mentioned, since you have handled true, check if the exchange has an exception attached to it or not.

Comment: Is it standard to check the exchange to make sure it's open when writing an aggregator?  I had assumed that the exchange would not be passed to the aggregator at all if it were closed.

Comment: If you have the Camel in Action book, then you can chapter about the splitter EIP as its covered there

Comment: Thanks Claus.  Is there a reason the aggregator example in that chapter checks if `exchange.getException()` is null rather than `exchange.isFailed()`?  Or are they pretty much the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Camel Documentation](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html) for the `stopOnException` Splitter option says

> Whether or not to stop continue processing immediately when an exception occurred. If disable, then Camel continue splitting and process the sub-messages regardless if one of them failed. You can deal with exceptions in the AggregationStrategy class where you have full control how to handle that.

This, along with Camel In Action, suggests that the two splitter exception handling options options are to deal with the exception in the Aggregator, or by using `stopOnException()`, which will stop the entire splitter iterator from continuing.

You can use either the `exchange.getException()` method, or `exchange.isFailed()` to test for exceptions and faults in the Aggregator.  If you've used `handled(true)` on the `onException` method, you'll have to use `exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT)`